# Problems with reading a file in java

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I'm doing a project for a class, but for the life of me I'm having the hardest time figuring out how to read text from a file. We have to create a traffic light that queues trucks and cars coming from North, South, East, and West. It's been a long time since I've done any coding, so I'm struggling immensely. I think it just reads the memory location. Here's my code for reading in a file.

```
package Project1;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class TrafficSim {

public String input;

public TrafficSim(String input)
{
    this.input = input;
    readFromFile();
}



private boolean readFromFile()
{
    File inputText = new File("input1.txt");

    try
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputText);

        while(scan.hasNextLine())
        {
            String direction = scan.nextLine();
            int num = scan.nextInt();
        }
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return false;
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    TrafficSim sim = new TrafficSim("input1.txt");
        System.out.println(sim);    
}

}
```

Comment: You need to override the `toString()` method in your TrafficSim class.

Comment: So I have to make a toString() method? Something like public String toString() { str = "";  System.out.println()}

Comment: `System.out.println(sim)` will invoke the `toString()` method on your `sim` object (inherited from the `Object` class), since you did'nt override it, you got the default output implementation (`getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())`).

Answer (score 2):

Your method readFromFile sure enough reads from a file, but then it doesn't do anything. All you do is read line by line, storing a line of text and an int in variables which are forgotten after each iteration of your while loop.

Your code `System.out.println(sim)` prints out whatever the `toString` method of your class returns, and since you didn't override that method it will print out the result of `Object.toString`, which is not what you want.

To put it simply, you're reading from a file but you're not doing anything with the contents that you read.

Comment: I hate to be a pain, but I'm not exactly sure on how to fix this. I'm completely lost.

Comment: The gist is, your `readFromFile` method reads from a file, line-by-line, but that's all it does. It reads each line and forgets each line. It doesn't **process** each line to do something with it.

Comment: Ok. I understand that, but how do I go about fixing it?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the information from the file?

Comment: Start by defining some data structure to hold the information from the file, whatever it is. Then, have `readFromFile` populate that data structure with the `direction` and `num` values it reads from the file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do....

```
public class TrafficSim {

    private String input;
    private String content;

    public TrafficSim(String input) {
        this.setInput(input);
        this.setContent(readFromFile());
    }

    private String readFromFile() {
        File inputText = new File(input);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputText);
            while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
                sb.append(scan.nextLine());
            }
            scan.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public void setInput(String input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TrafficSim sim = new TrafficSim("input1.txt");
        System.out.println(sim.getContent());
    }
}
```

The issue I see though is that you're not following the comments and suggestions already made.  ktm5124 was pretty clear on what the problem is.  At some point you're going to have to understand what is going on here and how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand what ktm5124 was saying, I just didn't know how to fix it. To better understand this, could you walk me through what you did and compare that to where I screwed up?